# Video tutorials on using the Windows command line

Tags: windows, video, dos

Are there any video tutorials about using the Windows command line?

Comment: Are you really still using MS-DOS? Or do you mean commandline commands in **Windows**?

Comment: Umm, yes. I meant Command line commands in windows.

Comment: This is not a programming question and probably belongs on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)

Comment: What did you try Googling? And it depends on what you want to do. Personally, I learn from reading, with the exception of Extremly Awesome But Complicated NLEs (like Lightworks).

Comment: Why would someone give me a -1 for asking how to learn, to even been pointed in the right direction. Of course I have tried google, But if there were a good Lynda course available that would be great. If not, no problem. But that is not a good reason to give me a -1....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not a video tutorial, I feel compelled to recommend [Rob van der Woude's Scripting Pages](http://www.robvanderwoude.com) as the richest resource (that I have found) for writing [batch scripts](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php) or [DOS (Windows cmd) commands](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchcommands.php).  The [Batch Files and Commands](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchcommands.php) page also gives a comprehensive list of which commands work in DOS vs. Windows, etc...  Whatever it is you're trying to do, you can probably figure-out how to do it there.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a great response that helps me a lot. When I start to become good at scripting, I will make a few videos to help users. It is difficult echen you have no idea with no direction even though Google has a lot of information having the right information does not come that easy. Thank you BryceAtNetwork23. I have been practicing a lot, but we all need to start from somewhere.

Comment: Glad to help, @Arthor.  Since you are fairly new to SO, I just wanted to remind you that the best way to thank someone is by accepting or giving a +1 to their answer.  Best of luck to you!

Comment: Thanks to Wahine.

This is a great site to learn so good stuff about scripts.

[1]: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/

Comment: As soon as I have a reputation of 15. I will, thank you :)

Comment: @Arthor: You can still _accept the answer_ without having 15 rep.